# lineNumbers in Reveal.js code block using pandoc - markdown conversion

Tags: markdown, pandoc, reveal.js

How can I get the line-numbers to display on the left edge of a code block in a Reveal.js slide show created with pandoc from a markdown document?

I have tried the following markdown:

```
---
title:  'Display Code-block Line Numbers'
date: 'Aug 2020'
---

--------

~~~ { .python .number-lines startFrom="1" data-line-numbers="3,4-5" }

def main():
  print( "hello pan" )

if __name__ == '__main__:
  main()

~~~

--------
```

With this command for pandoc:

```
pandoc -s -i -t revealjs --section-divs -o slides.html slides.md
```

I have also tried various alterations of the `fenced_code_attributes`:
`{ .python .number-lines }`, `{ .python .numberLines }`; and `pandoc` commands: removing the `-i` flag and trying some `--variable`s.

Also, the following does not work either: https://stackoverflow.com/a/55845381/5060792

Comment: You'll want https://github.com/pandoc/lua-filters/tree/master/revealjs-codeblock

Comment: That's great! The author of that filter is @sokotim, maybe he wants to write an answer about his work.

Comment: Unfortunately, the `startFrom="100"` attribute no longer works and everything starts from 1 no matter what.  Is there a way to fix this?

Comment: That should probably be raised as an issue on GitHub.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Reveal.js uses highlight.js with [highlightjs-line-numbers.js](https://github.com/wcoder/highlightjs-line-numbers.js) v2.6 for code highlighting and line numbering. Because of that,

- `data-line-numbers` is expected in the `<code>` element for line numbering
- the `startFrom` option or rather the `data-ln-start-from` attribute in the `<code>` element will not work (currently), hence this feature was added in highlightjs-line-numbers.js v2.8.

By default, pandoc's HTML output for code blocks works differently than reveal.js expects it. For example, fenced code data attributes are put in a wrapping `<div>`, where reveal.js can't find them. You will need to write raw HTML or change the output with a filter to use reveal.js' [code presentation features](https://revealjs.com/code/) like line numbering.

As @tarleb commented above, I wrote a lua filter which adapts pandoc's HTML output to support those features: https://github.com/pandoc/lua-filters/tree/master/revealjs-codeblock.